$p$ is a limit point of $S$ belonging to $\mathbb R$. Prove there exists a countably infinite subset of $S$ having $p$ as its limit point.
Is this correct?
Every neighborhood of $p$ in $\mathbb R$ contains an $s(n)$ belonging to $S$ not equal to $p$. Consider $I(1) = (p-1,p+1)$. Take $s(1)$ belonging to $I(1)$. Now take $I(2) = (p-s(1),p+s(1))$. Take $s(2)$ belonging to $I(2)$. Similarly $I(n) = (p-s(n-1),p+s(n-1))$ for $n>1$. This generates a countably infinite subset $(s(1),s(2),s(3),s(4)...)$ with $p$ as its limit point.
Update : As correctly pointed by Yathi the description of s(n)
was not sufficient. I was thinking of recursively defined intervals and without working out an example the specified s(n)
matched incorrectly to a description I had in mind. eg. $5$
is the limit point. Choose from $(4,6)$
. eg. $5.5$
. Choose from $(4.5,5.5)$
eg. $4.9$
Choose from $(4.9,5.1)$
& so on
That would have been if $s(n) < p$ Then $ I(n+1) = (s(n), 2p - s(n) )$. If $p > s(n), I(n+1) = (2p - s(n) , s(n) )$

Note that the length of the interval that you are considering must approach zero. A better argument looks like this:
Construct $\{x_n\}$ inductively as follows:
$x_1$ is an element of $S$ other than $p$ in $(p-1, p+1)$.
Once $x_k$ is constrcted, choose $x_{k+1}$ to be an elelement of $S$ other than $p, x_1, \dots, x_k$ such that $x_{k+1}\in \left(p-\frac{1}{k+1}, p+\frac{1}{k+1}\right)$. Such an $x_{k+1}$ always exists as $p$ is a limit point of $S$.
Here, length of the intervals is approaching zero. And for the infinite subest $\{x_k\}$ of $S$, $p$ is a limit point.
$\textbf{Update (by A. Random).}$ As correctly pointed by Yathi the description of $s(n)$ was not sufficient. I was thinking of recursively defined intervals and without working out an example felt the specified $s(n)$  matched  incorrectly to a description I had in mind. eg. $5$ is the limit point. Choose from $(4,6)$. eg. $5.5$. Choose from $(4.5,5.5)$ eg. $4.9$ Choose from $(4.9,5.1)$ & so on

The length of intervals $I(n)$ is approaching 0 since each s(n) is closer to p.

How do you ensure that each $s(n)$ is closer to $p$?

eg. $s(2)$ belongs to the open interval $(p - s(1), p + s(1) )$ so $p - s(2) < p - s(1)$

I am suggesting that you should have added one more phrase that $s(n)$ converges to $p$ or $s(n)$ has a subsequence which converges to $p$.  Your description is incomplete. Because, if you consider the interval $(0,1)$, clearly $1$ is a limit point. As per your description, I can choose $s(1)=0.5 \in (1-1,1+1)$. I can then choose $s(2) = 0.6 \in (1-s(1), 1+s(1))$. And then I can choose $s(3) = 0.45\in (p-s(2), p+s(2))$. Then again, I can choose $s(4) = 0.6 \in (p-s(3), p+s(3))$ and so on. Unless, i describe what are $s(n)$, I cannot claim that the interval length goes to zero.

You are correct. I was thinking of recursively defined intervals and without working out an example the specified $s(n)$  matched  incorrectly to a description I had in mind. eg. 5 is the limit point. Choose from (4,6). eg. 5.5. . Choose from (4.5,5.5) eg. 4.9 Choose from (4.9,5.1) & so on

That would have been if $s(n) < p$ The $ I(n+1) = (s(n), 2p - s(n) )$. If $p > s(n), I(n+1) = (2p - s(n) , s(n) )$
